# How to send a Adaptive card to Microsoft teams via Microsoft Graph API/SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How can we send a adaptive card to Microsoft Teams channel via Microsoft Graph API or Graph SDK. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send the Adaptive card using [Create chat message in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-3-cards) Graph API. Here is a sample code:

```
body: {
"body": {
"contentType": "html",
"content": "<attachment id="04b151bb-2f88-4f5b-9615-30b2a59d9adf">"
},
"attachments":[{
"id": "04b151bb-2f88-4f5b-9615-30b2a59d9adf",
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
"content": JSON.stringify(card.attachments[0].content)
}]
}
```

Comment: @Gousia-MST, How do we achieve this using Graph SDK?

Comment: Coud you please try the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_csharp) and try replacing the body content with Adaptive card.

Comment: This link is not working now. Could you please give the current url

Comment: Could you please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http